# Is there a way to call all functions inside an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var imgs = {
    a: function(){
        //...
    },
    b: function(){
        //...
    },
    c: function(){
        //...
    }
};
var preloadImgs = function(){
    imgs.a();
    imgs.b();
    imgs.c();
};
preloadImgs();
```

Is there a way to automate preloadImgs so it loads all the methods inside imgs at once, instead of me having to type every single one?

Comment: Why isn't `imgs` an array? Wouldn't it be simpler?

Comment: You can iterate the `imgs` values. Please share your attempt first.

Comment: @Quentin maybe the dup is an answer to OP's question, but it isn't going to really help them, because the question is more or less based on ... say on a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over all the values of the imgs object and call it if its a function

```js
var imgs = {
    a: function(){
        console.log('a');
    },
    b: function(){
        console.log('b');
    },
    c: function(){
        console.log('c');
    }
};
var preloadImgs = function(){
    Object.values(imgs).map(value => {
      if(typeof value === 'function') {
          value.call();
      }
    })
};
preloadImgs();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Object.values`

```
Object.values( imgs ).forEach( s => s() );
```

**Demo**

```js
var imgs = {
    a: function(){
       console.log("1");
    },
    b: function(){
       console.log("2");
    },
    c: function(){
       console.log("3");
    }
};
var preloadImgs = function(){
    Object.values( imgs ).forEach( s => s() );
};
preloadImgs();
```

**Edit**

If all the values in `img`s are not function, then you can apply the filter first

```
Object.values( imgs )
  .filter( s => typeof s === 'function' ) //filter out values which are function
  .forEach( s => s() ); //execute those functions
```